# Prestashop child theme error

Tags: prestashop

I have troubles creating child-theme for paid theme (it's arena2). I've created new folder

arena2-child
- Config
-- theme.yml
preview.png

Then I zip it and try to upload it to my prestaShop and I get error: "Incorrect config file".

My theme.yml:

name: arena2-child
parent: arena2
display_name: arena2-child

assets:
use_parent_assets: true

parent folder is called "arena2"

Comment: What is the version of the PrestaShop installation?

Comment: @Matt My presta is currently - 1.6.1.16